# Why is google maps not working in android(Via WebView)

Tags: java, android

Helllo this is what I have as of code. the rest is all running on a server, which im directing the mobile app to. I've tried everything, its not working.

Note: I'm using javascript Maps, on node js, but I really need to force it to work for the mobile, because I'm in a hackathon.

```
    test = findViewById(R.id.test);

    WebSettings man = test.getSettings();
    man.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    man.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    test.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    man.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    test.loadUrl("https://248531c1.ngrok.io");
```

Comment: The url as you have mentioned above it doesn't contain the map?

Comment: correct, it contains a website where it runs a static files and on click it will launch the algorithm to show the google map location for the peerson

Comment: I have just submit the form and its redirected to me on another page in this page still map is not showing(I am trying with chrome in my macbook)

Comment: its not going to work becauese I'm using Ngrok

Comment: Enabled DOM? Doc. Obj. Model

Comment: what do u meaen? can you clarify, please. I'm working with android here, is DOM a thing, I'm curious.